# Are rear-end collisions more dangerous in Compressed Natural Gas (CNG) than Petrol cars?

Tags: road-vehicles, safety

Is it more dangerous to be in a passenger car with compressed natural gas than with a petrol fuel tank when it comes to rear-end collisions?

[Lawrence Godwin, on eZine](http://EzineArticles.com/6501949) claims there is a explosion risk with CNG vehicles, although suggests that they are overall safer than petrol vehicles.

> A NG cars' fuel tank is usually located in the vehicle's trunk area, which reduces the space available for other uses, especially for long distance trips. There is also the danger of explosions during rear end collisions. Overall, CNG vehicles are considered to be safer than gasoline powered vehicles.

Further Info:

- The [Clean Vehicle Education Foundation](http://www.cleanvehicle.org/committee/technical/PDFs/Web-TC-TechBul2-Safety.pdf) don't address the rear-end risks, but suggest that, overall, CNG is safer than petrol.
- The [Cutting Through the Fog](http://cuttingthroughthefog.blogspot.com/2008/09/compressed-natural-gas-cng.html) blog speculates that a ruptured CNG tank is safer than a ruptured petrol tank.

Comment: related (and near dupe) http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9456/does-honda-civic-cng-fare-well-in-crash-safety-tests-as-claimed-by-its-manufactu

Comment: @ratchetfreak I've created this question based on feedback from other users on that other question.  It's in the linked bar on the right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both fuel types are incredibly dangerous. Just ask Michael Bay.

Comment: @Flimzy I am missing the reference here.  In his movies, diesel, petrol, and natural gas are equally glorious when blown up!